# QMake: test functions do not work as expected

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

In QtCreator 4.2.0 I try to use one *.pro file for building binaries for multiple hardware configurations.

In *Build & Run => Build Settings => Build Enviroment* I define the enviroment variable `TARGET` like as follows:

- *Build Settings A*: Variable `TARGET` has Value `bbb`
- *Build Settings B*: Variable `TARGET` has Value `desktop`

In the *pro*-file I use the following test functions:

```
equals($$TARGET,"bbb")
{
    message("setting include paths for bbb"))
    message($$TARGET)
}

equals($$TARGET,"laptop")
{
    message("setting include paths for laptop.")
    message($$TARGET)
}

contains($$TARGET,"*bbb*")
{
    message("setting include paths for bbb"))
    message($$TARGET)
}

contains($$TARGET,"*laptop*")
{
    message("setting include paths for laptop.")
    message($$TARGET)
}
```

And I get this output when running qmake:

```
Project MESSAGE: setting include paths for bbb
Project MESSAGE: bbb
Project MESSAGE: setting include paths for laptop.
Project MESSAGE: bbb
Project MESSAGE: setting include paths for bbb
Project MESSAGE: bbb
Project MESSAGE: setting include paths for laptop.
Project MESSAGE: bbb
Project MESSAGE: setting include paths for bbb
```

This makes no sense to me an I can't figure what I'm doing wrong here. Why are the parts after testing fro `laptop` executed?

By the way, I solved my problem by using `Scopes`. This works perfect for me:

```
CONFIG += $$(TARGET_HW)
desktop {
    message("setting include paths for laptop.")
}

cetec {
    message("setting include paths for cetec."))
}
```

But I'm still interested in the correct way of using test functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provide the correct syntax for the first test, as an example:

```
equals(TARGET,"bbb") {
    message("setting include paths for bbb"))
    message($$TARGET)
}
```

Please notice:

1. The curly brace is on the same line of the test.
2. The variable tested has no dollar signs, just the variable name

Comment: Ahhh, that's correct. Stupid mistake and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The opening brace must written on the same line as the condition (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scope-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

There are so many issues in your question, that there is place for another answer, adding to the previous correct ones:

1. as @daru says, you need to open the brace [in the same line](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scope-syntax) as the test function.
2. as @p-a-o-l-o says, [contains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#contains-variablename-value) and [equals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#equals-variablename-value) syntax require variable names as first arguments, without $$.
3. TARGET is an [internal variable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#target), that contains the base name of the project file by default. It becomes the name of the executable or library you are building.
4. You may use an [environment variable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variable-expansion) named TARGET, but then you should assign it to a qmake variable name with another name.

sample code:

```
TGT=$$(TARGET)

equals(TGT,"bbb") {
    message("$$TGT equals bbb"))
    message(TGT=$$TGT)
}

equals(TGT,"laptop") {
    message("$$TGT equals laptop")
    message(TGT=$$TGT)
}

contains(TGT,"bbb") {
    message("$$TGT contains bbb"))
    message(TGT=$$TGT)
}

contains(TGT,"top") {
    message("$$TGT contains top")
    message(TGT=$$TGT)
}
```

Comment: You're right. TARGET was a bad name for this example. What's the reason for you using an internal Qmake variable instead of an enviroment variable?

Comment: just to illustrate the different operators `$$` for qmake variables and `$$()` for environment variables, and TARGET is a valid name for an environment variable.